# Как зарегистрироваться в pyrogram без ввода в консоль номера телефона и кода? Можно ли это сделать (Как вариант) в окне в tkinter?

Tags: telegram, pyrogram

Проблема описана в названии. Я хочу создать свой клиент для телеграма, но понятное дело, что колхозный ввод номера и кода подтверждения не подходит. Можно ли как-то, за счёт переменных это всё-таки реализовать в удобном вводе типа Entry?
Если такое невозможно в pyrogram, пожалуйста посоветуйте библиотеки, где подобное возможно

Answer (score 0):

Есть ведь функции.
https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/send_code - отправляешь код для авторизации
https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/sign_in - авторизуешься.